# What happens if a DTD link leads nowhere?

Tags: xml, web-applications, weblogic, doctype, dtd

Fairly simple question, say I'm referencing a dtd for my XML's doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-web-app PUBLIC "-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 8.1//EN"
"http://www.bea.com/servers/wls810/dtd/weblogic810-web-jar.dtd">
```

And then say BEA goes down and never goes back up.

What would the consequences to my web application be?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the XML is used. Since a doctype might declare character references and the like that are used in the XML, it's not something that can simply be skipped by a parser like, say, an XML Schema reference could be ignored. So I'd reckon most parsers will run into trouble. They might appear to hang while trying to get the resource until they hit a timeout, if there's one to begin with for resource resolution.